# Can a UIButton response to touch event if it's position is out of its superview, but it is visible?

Tags: ios, uibutton, touch, response, uicontrol

Can a UIButton response to touch event if it's position is out of its superview, but it is visible?

```
UIView *view01 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)];
UIButton *button01 = [UIButton buttonWithStyle:UIButtonType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button01 addTarget:self action:@selector(testTouch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button01.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 60, 40);
[view01 addSubview:button01];

- (void)testTouch:(id)sender{
  NSLog(@"Touched.....");
}
```

.........

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `view01` to a view as well.

Comment: Sorry for me not to discribe the question clearly. I already add view01 to a view add can display them. But button01 (0, 200, 60, 40) is out of view01 (0,0,200,200), so i can not get response of it.